# C# Sort a list of Rectangles from left to right

Tags: c#, .net, opencv, emgucv, rectangles

I'm using EmguCV (OpenCV .NET Wrapper) for getting contours in an image using

`CVInvoke.FindContours(...)`

and then after that I loop through the contours found and create the bounding rectangles and add them to a list of rectangles.

```
List<Rectangle> recList = new List<Rectangle>();
```

[image]

For some reason, the FindContours does not return a natural ordering of segmented contours as we would define natural, How do I sort the list of rectangles that I have from **left to right**, and traversing from **top to bottom**?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue here. But using the `OpenCVSharp`.

My solution was a `LINQ` expression to sort the `Rectangle` list.

```
List<Rectangle> rectangles = new List<Rectangle>();
// ...insert list values...
rectList = rectList.OrderBy(r => r.Left).ThenBy(r => r.Top).ToList();
```